# TypeScript errors are not being shown on screen on vs code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsc

[image]

Although on compiling error is being shown on the terminal , but no error(red underline) is being shown on the the vs code editor. How to resolve this ?

Comment: do you have a tsconfig?

Comment: i just have the default tsconfig.json file which i generated using tsc --init .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by:

1. Going to Settings (on Mac "Code" -> "Preferences" -> "Settings")
2. Searching for something like "Typescript validate"
3. In the results that appear, making sure that "Enable/disable TypeScript validation" is checked.